# How to use \\p{Punct} in java to check for beginning of text line with: {"

Tags: java, regex

Given a *String* that begin's with the symbols: **{"** and ends with: **"}**. There are other punctuation's present in between the line aswell, like: , ' or "" etc. How to use java regex utility to know whether the given String starts with: **{"**. I am trying to return the Boolean value by using:

```
Pattern.matches(begin, string)
```

where

```
begin = "[\\p{Punct}&&[{]]"
```

and

```
string = {"name":"Aman"},{"surname":"Gupta"}.
```

(Please suggest regex option than JSON) I want to do it by using regex only. Please suggest a way how to achieve this.

Comment: You just want to check if your string is beginning with `{"` or I didn't well understand your question?

Answer (score 3):

You should try smth like this:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\{.*?\}");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(/*your string here*/);
 while (m.find()){
     String substringInBraces = m.group();
     /*do smth with your substring*/
 }
```

This will give you a substring of anything that might be between two nearest curly braces.

You might be interested in reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) and [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 2):

`Pattern.compile("^{").matcher(string).find()`

I don't know why you insist on using `\\p{Punct}`, it's totally unnecessary here.

Note that `Pattern.matches()` wants to match the entire string, so it is not useful when you only want to match something at the start of a string.

Comment: (^\\{\") and (\"\\}$) helped me... for beginning and ending of line respectively. Thanks for you quick response. God bless